# Detect silence(s) in audio channel from video stream

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video-streaming, channel, noise

We need to detect the 'silence'(s) in the audio channel of a video stream. We have been able to receive a UDP video stream and extract audio from it using the command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i udp://127.0.0.1:23000 -ab 3000k -ar 44100 -ac 1 test.wav
```

The audio file was saved only to verify whether audio has been extracted correctly or not.

To detect 'silence'(s) in the audio, we are using the `silencedetect` filter. We referred to some examples and it seems to work for audio files:

```
ffmpeg -i audio/file/path -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.25 -f null -
```

We are unable to detect silence(s) in the audio from a video stream. This is the command we came up with:

```
ffmpeg -y -i udp://127.0.0.1:23000 -ab 3000k -ar 44100 -ac 1 -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.25 -f null -
```

What is it that we are doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to increase the noise threshold level? (Increment by 3 dB and see at what level it starts to flag silence spots)

Comment: When we use silencedetect with an audio file, we get 'start timestamp', 'end timestamp' and duration seconds. What we would like to confirm is if it's even possible to get these values in a livestream?

Comment: This should work. As a side note, you don't need to transcode the audio, so can remove the `-ab 3000k -ar 44100 -ac 1` - just use `-c copy`.